# How can i import the data from dataset of images when i have given a Zip file of type Gz file. an i have already extracted?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, data-handling

i am working on a new assingment where i have asked to bulit a CNN classification model .how to handel when data is given in Gz file type and have diffent folders with images.

Before now have only worked on csv type file but currently i am not able to how to handel this type of data having only images in different folder and that folder contains in gz type of file.

Answer (score 0):

Before going further you need to know what **.gz** is. It's a file format like **zip**. In order to uncompress the file, you can follow the following commands on linux

`tar -xvzf file.tar.gz`

On Windows - Use winrar or winzip.

Comment: thanks,i have already unzip the file in windows now there are nine folders in it and in those nine folders i have one folder contaning images how can i make a data based of thoes images saperately by taking those images from those folders to train and test

Comment: @SudeepPandey, please use `tree` command and put the folder structure